# Reporting Services 2016 Multiple Email Accounts

Tags: ssrs, database-mail, reporting, ssrs-2016

Is there a way to configure SSRS 2016 to be able to send email from more than one email account?  I am looking to setup something that is department specific for our organization.  Right now its defaulting to one department and it doesn't really fit our growth plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only specify one mail account per SSRS installation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make sure that the e-mail addresses are separated by ; that is [space][semicolon][space].

So for example, if you want to send the report to JCB@company.com and Kurt@company.com, your CC string should be added.

I tried like this and it works for me (for Test).  It should be:

> ‘JCB@company.com; Kurt@company.com’ AS [CC]

Check this link:

> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f12dc51f-a684-41a4-b419-cda5530787f5/can-multiple-email-account-be-defined-for-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I was not looking for a way to send TO more than one email but rather FROM more than one email account.

Comment: Oh, It's my bad Unfortunately we can't do that, SSRS allows to define only one email account to send the emails. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/714656/allow-to-define-multiple-sender-address